# add routing in Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The earlier versions of Angular have asked if you'd like to *Add Angular routing?* as you run through the `ng new` command.

This question is gone in Angular CLI v12 and so are the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tags in the **app.component.html** file.

Is there a simple command argument to include routing when you make a new app?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: What about the `--routing` flag in the CLI? So `ng new project-name --routing`

Comment: https://angular.io/cli/new all of the options can be found here